# Rectangular section inside a circle

Tags: android, android-canvas

I was able to draw the circle and the text. The only thing that I am missing is that "rectangular" section inside the circle. Any clue on how can I do this?

[image]

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the order I would draw in:

[image]

1. drawRect to form the base
2. drawRect to draw the middle line section
3. draw the frame (a rect with a hole in it - this could be challenging)
4. draw the progress bar (many approaches to this)
5. draw the information onto the display

Sorry I haven't provided more detail, currently very busy.